# Fetch nested items using GraphQL query in JavaScript Amplify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, nested, aws-amplify

**Definition**:
A **Team** can have many **Users** and 1 user as manager:

```
type Team {
  id: ID!
  title: String
  manager: User @connection
  users: [User] @connection(name: "TeamUsers")
}
```

The **User** type is defined as:

```
type User {
  id: ID!
  username: String
  team: [Team] @connection(name: "TeamUsers")
}
```

Using JS, I can access the **Team** manager's username:

```
{teams.map((team) => {
  return(
    <li>{team.manager.username}</li>
  )
}
```

**Problem**: I can't get the usernames of users in the team using either:

```
{teams.map((team) => {
  return(
    <li>{team.users.username}</li>
    // or
    <li>{team.users.map((user) => {user.username})}</li>
  )
}
```

**PS)** I am using AWS Amplify and I'm fetching teams using the following code:

```
  const fetchTeams = async () => {
    try {
      const teamsData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listTeams));
      const teamsList = teamsData.data.listTeams.items;
      setClients(teamsList);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`fetchTeams failed.`, error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: `team.users.username` doesn't work because `users` is an array. `team.users.map((user) => {user.username})` is the right approach but your callback arrow function doesn't `return` anything.

Comment: Noted. But I'm getting TypeError: team.users.map is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

As @Bergi said in the comment.
I think

`<li>{team.users.map((user) => {user.username})}</li>`

=>

`<li>{team.users.map(user => user.username)}</li>`

will fix your issues